# query resort by multiple columns and check when it finds results by one column

Tags: mysql

I use this query to select webcams by resort or skiarea or state name. What I would like to know is when it has only results for resort.  Can I flag the query once it finds a record via resort and not via skiarea or state?

```
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
                        sv_cam.image,
                        sv_cam.cam_id,
                        sv_orte.resort,
                        sv_canton.can_id,
                        sv_canton.canton,
                        sv_country.country
          FROM  sv_cam
          LEFT JOIN sv_orte ON sv_cam.res_id = sv_orte.res_id AND status=0
          LEFT JOIN sv_region ON sv_orte.reg_id = sv_region.reg_id
          INNER JOIN sv_canton ON sv_orte.can_id = sv_canton.can_id
          INNER JOIN sv_country ON sv_canton.cou_id = sv_country.cou_id
          WHERE (resort='$region' OR ski='$region' OR canton='$region')
```

Comment: please edit your question

Comment: what do you want me to edit maku

Comment: what your trying to achieve, its not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand - the answer to your question is NO - it is not possible to "flag" entire query results any way.

But it is possible to flag each row by conditions it matches:

```
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
                        sv_cam.image,
                        sv_cam.cam_id,
                        sv_orte.resort,
                        sv_canton.can_id,
                        sv_canton.canton,
                        sv_country.country,
                        resort='$region' AS foundByResort,
                        ski='$region' AS foundBySki,
                        canton='$region' AS foundByCanton
          FROM  sv_cam
          LEFT JOIN sv_orte ON sv_cam.res_id = sv_orte.res_id AND status=0
          LEFT JOIN sv_region ON sv_orte.reg_id = sv_region.reg_id
          INNER JOIN sv_canton ON sv_orte.can_id = sv_canton.can_id
          INNER JOIN sv_country ON sv_canton.cou_id = sv_country.cou_id
          WHERE (resort='$region' OR ski='$region' OR canton='$region')
```

This will add three columns to each row with 1 in each that matches its part of the condition.

You can then check all rows for zeroes in the conditions you "do not want".

Or you can use three queries - each for one condition - then you will see it directly, but you might get duplicate rows if some row matches more than one condition.

Or you may have your original query and then run second one:

```
 SELECT count(1) AS itemsFound
          FROM  sv_cam
          LEFT JOIN sv_orte ON sv_cam.res_id = sv_orte.res_id AND status=0
          LEFT JOIN sv_region ON sv_orte.reg_id = sv_region.reg_id
          INNER JOIN sv_canton ON sv_orte.can_id = sv_canton.can_id
          INNER JOIN sv_country ON sv_canton.cou_id = sv_country.cou_id
          WHERE (ski='$region' OR canton='$region')
```

And if you get zero rows then you know there are no results for ski or canton. Otherwise you get one row with one column containing number of matches.